# Does Gnome Shell use Mutter?

Tags: gnome3, window-manager, gnome-shell, mutter

In [Wikipedia is written](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Shell) that Gnome Shell in Gnome 3 uses Mutter window manager.

But `ps x | grep mutter` shows that Mutter is not running. Moreover I had experience with working Gnome Shell *before* I installed Mutter.

Does Gnome Shell really use Mutter? Which WM are used and which can be used with Gnome Shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `mutter` is used by `gnome-shell` but it's used as a library. [The `mutter` binary is just a tiny program that links against `libmutter`](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2011-March/msg03083.html).
You could try like this:

```
lsof | grep mutter
```

Comment: Yes, I see, mutter is used, but as a library not as an executable

Comment: Thank you. I was hacking on mutter and was wondering why my changes has no effect in gnome session after I copy mutter into `$(which mutter)`. You answer explains it all, I had to copy `build/src/libmutter-9.so.0.0.0` instead. Now it works!