# Open programs with a specified position and size in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, gnome3, window-management

I use *Gnome 3* alias *Gnome Shell* on Fedora 20. `echo $GDMSESSION` outputs `gnome` and `pgrep -l "compiz|metacity|mutter|openbox"` produces no output.

How can I open each window as if I'd done a <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> or <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd>, but one time on the left, one time on the right?

#### Example

- I log in
- I open Sublime, this goes to the half left with half width
- I open Firefox, this goes to the half right with half width (in auto!)

Comment: You cannot detect `mutter` with `pgrep`, see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56237/22142). As to automatically snapping windows left-right, I don't think this can be done via configuration settings (`dconf`/`gsettings`) but it's definitely doable via gnome-shell extensions. Check https://extensions.gnome.org first, maybe there is something that does what you want (`shellshape`, `shelltile` and `putwindows` come to mind, although I have not played with them enough to know if they're up to the job).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I'll take shelltile's code and do it by hand. Do you think it's possible to cout how many windows are open ? If so it will be quite to place each windows.

Comment: It is possible to count the open windows e.g. [`windowNavigator`](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/10/windownavigator/) is an extension that assigns numbers to each open window: [screenshot](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/_1QSDkzYY2vc/TZ2mpckXulI/AAAAAAAAD7A/_DgCtJBy1Pg/s2000/shell-extension2.png) so you could look into that. Also, if you're on gnome-shell ≥ 3.12, note the `.js` files are wrapped up in a binary so in order to play with these files you'll have to 'unpack' them - more [here](http://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2014/03/24/keeping-gnome-shell-approachable/). HTH.

Comment: Thanks for all don_crissti, I close the topic as resolved and post later the code if I've got time to do it.